# Hide/Show Web Part by clicking a Hyperlink in a carousel Sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, web-parts

I am trying to use a standard carousel with jQuery to hide or show certain webpart zones on a page.  I have a class added to the < li > of Section1, Section2, etc. and would like it top open WebPartWPQ5 when you click Section1 etc.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').hide(); 

       $(".Section1").click(function(){
      $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').toggle(); 
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Each li would open a web part below it that is hidden initially.

```
 <ul id="jtabs" class="jtabs"> 
 <li class="ShowSection1"><a href="#">Budget</a></li> 
 <li class="ShowSection2"><a href="#">Compensation</a></li> 
 </ul>
```

There are 5 jTabs That should open one web part and close any that is open when it is clicked

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
     $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').hide();       
     $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').hide(); 
         $("ul").on('click', 'li.ShowSection1', function(){     
         $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').toggle(); }); 

         $("ul").on('click', 'li.ShowSection2', function(){    
         $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').toggle(); 
   }); 
});
```

---

Here is an example of the web part code.  I would think the web part ID could be used because it is always a unique ID.

```
     <WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{D0ADB7E7-8348-4604-96BA-6B22745C057F}" >
   <WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
   <Title>Content Editor</Title>
     <FrameType>None</FrameType>
     <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
     <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
     <PartOrder>8</PartOrder>
     <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
     <Height />
     <Width />
     <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
     <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
     <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
     <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
     <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
     <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
     <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
     <DetailLink />
     <HelpLink />
     <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
     <Dir>Default</Dir>
     <PartImageSmall />
     <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
     <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
     <IsIncludedFilter />
     <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
     <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
     <ID>g_7ac31086_17de_44c1_9a0b_44a01f67a452</ID>
     <ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">/sites/WSS001905/SiteAssets/Carousel/carousel.txt</ContentLink>
     <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
     <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
   </WebPart>
   </WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
```

---

Here is the full carousel file:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/Carousel/core.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/Carousel/jslideshow.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/Libraries/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/Libraries/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/Libraries/jslideshow-1.0.0.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body{ margin: 0px;}
h1{font-size: 24px; margin-bottom: 20px;}
p{font-size: 14px;}
/* clean gray
*******************************************************************************/
button.clean-gray {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eeeeee), to(#cccccc));
  /* Saf4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333;
  font: bold 11px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #eee;
  width: 150px; }
  button.clean-gray:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dddddd), to(#bbbbbb));
    /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #bbbbbb);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #bbbbbb);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #bbbbbb);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #bbbbbb);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #dddddd, #bbbbbb);
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ddd; }
  button.clean-gray:active {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #aaaaaa, 0 1px 0 0 #eeeeee;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #aaaaaa, 0 1px 0 0 #eeeeee;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #aaaaaa, 0 1px 0 0 #eeeeee;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #aaaaaa, 0 1px 0 0 #eeeeee;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #aaaaaa, 0 1px 0 0 #eeeeee; }
    .controls{
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8; margin-top: 10px; padding: 10px;
    width: 604px;
    }
    .controls h2{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .container{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    width: 624px; margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    z-index:-1;
    }
    .footer{
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 11px;
    }
    .download{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .cc{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: solid #d8d8d8;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jslideshow">
    <ul class="jslides">
        <li>
            <div class="carousel-image"><img src="../SiteAssets/Carousel/budget.JPG" width="440" height="300" alt="Budget Image"></div>

            <div class="carousel-description">
                <h2 class="ShowSection1"><a  href="#">Budget</a></h2>&nbsp; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in massa ipsum. <a href="#">&raquo; Find out more</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="carousel-image"><img src="../SiteAssets/Carousel/comp.JPG" width="440" height="300" alt="Budget Image"></div>

            <div class="carousel-description">
                <h2><a href="#">Compensation</a></h2>&nbsp; Fusce fringilla nibh ut nibh sodales vehicula. Sed metus nunc, mattis non fermentum quis, viverra non est. <a href="#">&raquo; Find out more</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="carousel-image"><img src="../SiteAssets/Carousel/expenses.JPG" width="440" height="300" alt="JQuery Carousel Example Image 3"></div>

            <div class="carousel-description">
                <h2><a href="#">Expenses</a></h2>&nbsp; Sed lorem massa, laoreet sed viverra eu, ultrices sit amet libero. Curabitur lorem dolor, adipiscing et venenatis a, pharetra ac nisi. Nunc laoreet posuere faucibus. <a href="#">&raquo; Find out more</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="carousel-image"><img src="../SiteAssets/Carousel/FinResults.JPG" width="440" height="300" alt="JQuery Carousel Example Image 4"></div>

            <div class="carousel-description">
                <h2><a href="#">Results</a></h2>&nbsp; Phasellus nec nunc est. Cras elit arcu, malesuada nec venenatis ac, sollicitudin in magna. <a href="#">&raquo; Find out more</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="carousel-image"><img src="../SiteAssets/Carousel/Misc.JPG" width="440" height="300" alt="JQuery Carousel Example Image 5"></div>

            <div class="carousel-description">
                <h2><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></h2>&nbsp; Quisque sit amet tortor eu tellus suscipit pretium. Nunc dolor mauris, sagittis ut laoreet non, vulputate ut sapien. <a href="#">&raquo; Find out more</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="jtabs" class="jtabs">

        <li class="ShowSection1"><a href="#">Budget</a></li>

        <li class="ShowSection2"><a href="#">Compensation</a></li>

        <li class="ShowSection3"><a href="#">Expenses</a></li>

        <li class="ShowSection4"><a href="#">Results</a></li>

        <li class="ShowSection5"><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>

    </ul>
</div><script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() { //Standand variables
        $( "#button" ).click(function() {
            $('.jslideshow').jslideshow('updateSlideshow', {
            'effectType' : $( "#effectTypes" ).val(),
            'interval' : $( "#intervalSpeed" ).val(),
            'animationspeed' : $( "#animationSpeed" ).val()
            //'slidedown': "element.slideDown(plugin.settings.animationspeed, easing);"
         }); // calls the init method
    return false;
    });
    });
    })(jQuery);

</script>
<div class="controls" style="display:none">
<h2>Slideshow Controls</h2>
<label for="effectTypes">Effect Type</label>
<select name="effectTypes" id="effectTypes">
    <option value="core_fadein">
        Fade In (Jquery Core)
    </option>

    <option value="core_show">
        Show (Jquery Core)
    </option>

    <option value="core_slidedown">
        Slide Down (Jquery Core)
    </option>

    <option value="jqueryui_blind">
        Blind (Jquery UI)
    </option>

    <option value="jqueryui_clip">
        Clip (Jquery UI)
    </option>

    <option value="jqueryui_drop">
        Drop (Jquery UI)
    </option>

    <option value="jqueryui_fade">
        Fade (Jquery UI)
    </option>

    <option value="jqueryui_fold">
        Fold (Jquery UI)
    </option>

    <option value="jqueryui_puff">
        Puff (Jquery UI)
    </option>

    <option value="jqueryui_slide">
        Slide (Jquery UI)
    </option>

    <option value="custom_animate_1">
        Custom Animation (Jquery UI)
    </option>

</select> 
<label for="intervalSpeed">Interval Speed</label>
<select name="intervalSpeed" id="intervalSpeed">
    <option value="500">
        500ms
    </option>

    <option value="600">
        600ms
    </option>

    <option value="700">
        700ms
    </option>

    <option value="800">
        800ms
    </option>

    <option value="900">
        900ms
    </option>

    <option value="1000">
        1000ms
    </option>
    <option value="1500">
        1500ms
    </option>
    <option value="2000">
        2000ms
    </option>
    <option value="2500">
        2500ms
    </option>
    <option value="3000">
        3000ms
    </option>
</select>
<label for="animationSpeed">Animation Speed</label>
    <select name="animationSpeed" id="animationSpeed">
    <option value="200">
        200ms
    </option>

    <option value="300">
        300ms
    </option>

    <option value="400">
        400ms
    </option>

    <option value="500">
        500ms
    </option>

    <option value="600">
        600ms
    </option>

    <option value="700">
        700ms
    </option>

    <option value="800">
        800ms
    </option>

    <option value="900">
        900ms
    </option>

    <option value="1000">
        1000ms
    </option>
    <option value="1500">
        1500ms
    </option>
    <option value="2000">
        2000ms
    </option>
    <option value="2500">
        2500ms
    </option>
    <option value="3000">
        3000ms
    </option>
</select>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;">
<button href="#" id="button" class="clean-gray">Run Effect</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() { //Standand variables

$('.jslideshow').jslideshow({
    'interval' : '4000',
    'animationspeed' : '1000',
    'effectType' : 'jqueryui_slide'
}); // calls the init method


});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<hr>
</body>
```

---

The code you provided would change the image but not hide or show the web parts.  here is the full carousel which scyles through and woud open the links if needed, but it needs to show the web part on the page below it.  I appreciate all the help you have given so far, but still no go.

Comment: You have an extra `});` in there

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `});' in your code. Also, if you want to be able to click on any section then make sure you make your class more generic. As you have it, it seems like you only want '#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5' to show if you click section 1.

How about something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class='section'>Section1</li>
  <li class='section'>Section2</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').hide(); 

  $("ul").on('click', 'li.section', function(){
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').toggle(); 
  });
});
```

I placed the class 'section' on each `li` just in case they contain other `li`.

**EDIT**
After seeing the images of the rendered HTML, the following should work. I've included an example jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/oBEgEpe/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slides = $('.jslides li');

  // Hide all but the first
  $(slides).hide();
  $(slides).eq(0).show();

  $('#jtabs').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slide_number = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $(slides).hide();
    $(slides).eq(slide_number).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Vlad, this works well for one web part, but the ul has 5 li that should open one when it closes another.  Am i wrong in thinking this should be a loop?

Comment: So each li should open a different? web part? It would be helpful if you could include the html of your web parts, so we can see what the relation of the ul is to the web parts and if there are any classes and so on.

Comment: Yes sir, each LI would open a web part below it that is hidden initially.  
        <ul id="jtabs" class="jtabs">
            <li class="ShowSection1"><a href="#">Budget</a></li>
            <li class="ShowSection2"><a href="#">Compensation</a></li> 
        </ul> 
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').hide();
$('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').hide();  
$("ul").on('click', 'li.ShowSection5', function(){
$('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').toggle(); 
});
$("ul").on('click', 'li.ShowSection5', function(){
$('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').toggle();  
});
});

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Comment: Can you add classes to the web parts and an attribute to each li? I still don't know what the web parts html looks like and it's hard to write a simple solution without knowing the html structure.

Comment: If you can add classes and attributes, then it becomes nice and simple. You add a click event to the ul, and hide all web parts except the one associated with the li, by hiding the class, then show the web part associated with the li via an attribute like `data-web_part='#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5'.

Comment: I tried adding a class to the XSL itself for the web part and that seemed to do damage to the design.  It would not display the carousel or any of the web parts then.  That't why I am thinking using the Web part ID may work but I am not sure I know how to reference it.

Comment: Ok, if you can't add classes then the id should work. It just means a little more code. Can you add attributes to the LIs that you want to click? If we can add the attribute data-webpart_id="#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5" and so on, then we can use that to determine which li will toggle which webpart.

Comment: I am still having issues, here are links to what it looks like and what the code looks like for the Html.  Maybe that will help decifer something.  I'm at a loss.

http://imgur.com/zhhmi8C
http://imgur.com/a/hVsxr#5DVWMST

Comment: @ahdrum87 I updated with an example based on your images. In the future, you should include that html in your question.

Comment: Sorry for that.  I have updated with the full txt file I am using.  The page needs to hide or show the webpart not do things with the images (thats already in place) thanks Vlad!

Comment: I give up! Hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: Vlad, I truely appreciate all your help.  

Anyone else want to take a stab at it?